# Crash is not reporting to Crashlytics Dashboard from a App Store App

Tags: ios, crashlytics

We have application released on iOS app store. And as per the guidelines the crashlytics SDK is integrated and also calling `[Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"API_KEY"]` as well. What could be the different reasons that the crashes are not getting updated on the Crashlytics Dashboard.

How we can verify or debug, the app which having the Crashlytics sdk integrated and initialised appropriately  or not?

Comment: Why don't you fire an email to the Crashlytics support team. They are usually very good and respond pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

Before you launched, did you verify that crashes were getting reported? If not, then you may have a conflicting Exception/Signal Handler preventing Crashlytics from doing it's job.

Here's how you can throw a signal:

```
-(void) throwSignal {
    int i = 12345;
    NSLog(@"%@", i);
}
```

To throw an uncaught exception simply do the following:

```
[NSException raise:@"test version 3.3.2 crashy" format:@"awesomeness"];
```

If you were able to get crash reports before launch, then there may be something happening with Crashlytics ingest of the reports and I would contact their support team.

Answer (score 0):

We are getting now crash reports for app store build. We had a provided .dSym file to the crashlytics team, they have uploaded the same in their db.